# Update textbox to a different form from backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, textbox, backgroundworker

I have two forms, Form1 and Newform. Form1 has two buttons and a textbox and Newform has its own textbox. I am using a settext sub to invoke a delegate sub in the backgroundworker to update the textbox in both forms.

The textbox in Form1 seems to be updating but the textbox in Newform isn't updating.

Is there something that I'm missing if I want to update the textbox on a different form?

Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
Dim stopbit As Boolean
Dim TestingComplete As Boolean
Dim ReadValue As Double
Dim FinalValue As Double

Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByRef Txtbox As TextBox, ByVal Txt As String)

'Thread Safe textbox update routine
Private Sub SetText(ByRef Txtbox As TextBox, ByVal Txt As String)

    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
    Console.WriteLine(Txtbox.InvokeRequired & "  textbox invokerequired")

    If Txtbox.InvokeRequired Then
        Try
            'MsgBox("inside settext")
            Txtbox.Invoke(New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText), Txtbox, Txt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        Txtbox.Text = Txt
        Txtbox.Update()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    newform.Show()
End Sub

Function ReadTemp() As Double
    ReadValue = ReadValue / 2
    Return ReadValue
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim starttime As Integer
    Dim EllapsedTime As Integer
    Dim OldValue As Double = 0
    Dim NewValue As Double = 0
    Dim Difference As Double = 1
    Dim Margin As Double = 0.1

    stopbit = False
    starttime = My.Computer.Clock.TickCount
    Do
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        OldValue = NewValue
        NewValue = ReadTemp()
        Difference = Math.Abs(NewValue - OldValue)
        SetText(Me.TextBox1, Difference.ToString)
        SetText(newform.TextBox1, Difference.ToString)
        newform.Refresh()
        EllapsedTime = My.Computer.Clock.TickCount - starttime


    Loop Until EllapsedTime > 5000 Or stopbit = True ' Or Difference < Margin
    FinalValue = NewValue
    TestingComplete = True

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    stopbit = True
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        ReadValue = 100000
        TestingComplete = False
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Test)

        Do
            Thread.Sleep(200)
        Loop Until TestingComplete = True
        MsgBox("Final Value  " & FinalValue)
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Often times when setting a property on a thread other than the UI thread, you'll need to refresh the control. You're using the Update method right now, but try using the Refresh method instead.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the recommendation. I tried changing txtbox.update() to txtbox.refresh() but it still didn't update.

Comment: If you don't mind (simply for testing purposes), in your DoWork event comment out `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Test)` with the following: `newform.TextBox1.Invoke(Sub() \n newform.TextBox1.Text = i \n newform.TextBox1.Refresh() End Sub)` (just replace the `\n` character with a new line

Comment: I get Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll in the output

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.6.01055

Comment: @David : You don't need to call neither `Refresh()` nor `Update()`. The control redraws itself when the property is changed. Also he's not changing it from the background thread (that would cause an exception), `Invoke()` moves execution to the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to that you're using the *default instance* of `newform`. In VB.NET default form instances is a feature that allows you to access a form via its type name without having to manually create an instance of it.

In other words it lets you do this:

```
newform.Show()
newform.TextBox1.Text = "Something"
```

...instead of doing it the correct way, which is this:

```
Dim myNewForm As New newform
myNewForm.Show()
myNewForm.TextBox1.Text = "Something"
```

Above we create a new instance of `newform` called `myNewForm`. This is required to be able to use *most* objects in the framework (including forms). However, VB.NET simplifies this behaviour by offering to create the instance for you, which is what is going on in my first example.

The problem with these *default instances* is that they are thread-specific, meaning a new instance is created *for every thread* that you use this behaviour in.

Thus the form you refer to when you do:

```
newform.Show()
```

...is not the same form that you refer to in your thread, because a new instance has been created for it *in that thread*:

```
'This is not the same "newform" as above!
SetText(newform.TextBox1, Difference.ToString)
```

The solution to this is of course to create the instance yourself, allowing you to have full control over what's going on:

```
Dim newFrm As New newform

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    newFrm.Show()
End Sub

...your code...

Sub Test()
    ...your code...

    SetText(newFrm.TextBox1, Difference.ToString)

    ...even more of your code...
End Sub
```

---

As a side note you can remove your calls to `newform.Refresh()` and `Txtbox.Update()`. These just cause unnecessary overhead by forcing the form and text boxes to redraw themselves, which is already done when you change any of their properties that affect their contents/design (so you are essentially making them redraw themselves twice).

Also, if you want to make invoking to the UI thread *simpler* and you are using Visual Studio/Visual Basic 2010 ***or newer***, you could switch to using [***lambda expressions***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) instead of regular delegates. They're much easier to use and allows you to create whole methods in-line that can be invoked on the UI thread.

For this purpose I've written an extension method called `InvokeIfRequired()` which lets you invoke *any* method/function on the UI thread, checking `InvokeRequired` for you. It's similar to what you have now, only it works for any control (not just text boxes) and with lambda expressions, allows you to run any code you want on the UI.

You can use it by adding a module to your project (`Add New Item... > Module`) and naming it `Extensions`. Then put this code inside it:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Invokes the specified method on the calling control's thread (if necessary, otherwise on the current thread).
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Control">The control which's thread to invoke the method at.</param>
    ''' <param name="Method">The method to invoke.</param>
    ''' <param name="Parameters">The parameters to pass to the method (optional).</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Method As [Delegate], ByVal ParamArray Parameters As Object()) As Object
        If Parameters IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
            Parameters.Length = 0 Then Parameters = Nothing

        If Control.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Return Control.Invoke(Method, Parameters)
        Else
            Return Method.DynamicInvoke(Parameters)
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

This allows you to invoke either one line of code by doing:

```
Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub() Me.TextBox1.Text = Difference.ToString())
```

Or to invoke a whole block of code by doing:

```
Me.InvokeIfRequired(Sub()
                        Me.TextBox1.Text = Difference.ToString()
                        newFrm.TextBox1.Text = Difference.ToString()
                        Me.BackColor = Color.Red 'Just an example of what you can do.
                    End Sub)
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the explanation. I got the code working as well.

Comment: @phillip87 : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi Vincent, I'm currently running into some problems with this method. It seems that when I close Form1 then try to open it again, I get an error saying that I can't access instances that have been disposed. Can you point me to a resource that can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
YourSubHere

Me.Invoke(Sub()
          Form1.Textbox1.text="some text1"
          Form2.Textbox2.text="some text2"
          End Sub)
End Sub
```

Or if it's a one liner.

```
Me.Invoke(Sub() Form1.Textbox1.text="some text1")
```

Depending on what you need, you could invoke just some control like:

```
Textbox1.invoke(Sub() Textbox1.text="some text1")
```

Comment: You ought to check [**`InvokeRequired`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx) as well. If invoking isn't necessary (if we're already in the UI thread) doing so is a highly unnecessary bottleneck. Also, `TextBox1.Invoke()` is no different to `Me.Invoke()`, it will look up the parent form anyway.

Comment: When he is accessing another form from background thread invoke will always be required.

Comment: Of course, but isn't it better to be on the safe side? If something changes in the future I think it's better to not have to change all one's code. :)

Comment: I like to keep it as short as possible.